# Queries in devMode

Tags: database, queries, devmode

When I look at the console log when devMode is enabled, I notice there's a lot going on, and I'm not sure if what I'm seeing is normal or not.

There are dozens of

`[trace][system.db.CDbCommand]\nQuerying SQL: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM`

or:

`[profile][system.db.CDbCommand.query] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT...`

What worries me slightly is that there are mentions of ALL the fields in ALL the tables in my DB, even those not used in the current template/entry and with `{% cache %}` enabled.

Should I panic or is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I panic or is this normal?

Normal. Each of those `[trace]` and `[profile]` log entries will have a stack backtrace listed under them showing you exactly what led up to that query, if you're curious.  Usually the `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` query is coming from an ActiveRecord when Yii queries to get metadata for the underlying table it represents.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I tried running an empty template and I still see the queries, so I won't worry about it too much. I also noticed there are 11 queries on an empty template but I guess this is normal as well.

Comment: Well, Craft does need to run a few queries to operate. :)